# How to make concept that checks type equality for any templated type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

In C++ you can make concepts that check for specific type equality:

```
template<typename T> concept Int = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
template<typename T> concept String = std::is_same_v<T, std::string>;
```

Is it possible to make a concept that checks for type equality of any type, so I could make templates looking something like this:

```
template<ValidType<int>... Ints> void passInts(Ints... ints) {}
template<ValidType<std::string>... Strings> void passStrings(Strings... strings) {}
```

That way I would only need to write a single concept checking for type equality. I know I could use `conjunction` for this but I think concepts are much cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mean, you could write a concept to do that. Or you could just use `std::same_as`:

```
template<std::same_as<int>... Ints> void passInts(Ints... ints)
template<std::same_as<std::string>... Strings> void passStrings(Strings... strings)
```

When a concept is used against a template parameter pack, it is applied individually to each of the types in the pack.

Of course, this may not quite do what you need. The reason being that `same_as` is *very serious* about its name. If you want to invoke perfect forwarding through forwarding references, template argument deduction can start deducing the types as references to `T`. Which re not the "`same_as`" `T`.

So if you want to allow for perfect forwarding, you need a different concept: `similar_to`. Which sadly is not in the standard library, despite how simple and useful it is:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept similar_to = std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<T1>, T2>;
```

Note that this assumes that `T2` has no reference or cv qualifiers. You can make a version that removes cvref from both.

Now, you can do this:

```
template<similar_to<int> ...Ints> void passInts(Ints && ...ints)
template<similar_to<std::string> ...Strings> void passStrings(Strings && ...strings)
```

And now you get perfect forwarding back.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't seem to make any attempt at perfect-forwarding and takes everything by-value instead, in which case `std::same_as` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what you want but you can add the type you want to check for as second template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename U> concept ValidType = std::is_same_v<T, U>;
```

Then your two examples will work in that all template arguments will be restricted to `int` or `std::string` respectively.

In fact that is exactly what the `std::same_as` concept from the standard library already does. So just use that instead of `ValidType` to get additional benefits of constraint subsumption lacking in the simple variant above.